# Android clear application data

Tags: android

How do I clear my application data with the app closing by using `ActivityManager`

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean res = am.clearApplicationUserData();
```

I tried using the code above and the app quit without any warning

I want to be able to clear the data and then write new database on the flag and restart the app after writing the data to `SharedPrefences`

**NOTE**: `am.clearApplicationUserData()` works to clear the user data but I'm not getting back the flag to determine if the clear was successful or not.

**Log :** 
 ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{65dc437 u0 {package}/{package}.WelcomeActivity t794}

ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{65dc437 u0 {package}/{package}WelcomeActivity t794 f}

ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{65dc437 u0 {package}/c{package}WelcomeActivity t794 f}

ActivityManager: Force stopping {package} appid=10142 user=-1:clearApplicationUserData

ActivityManager: Killing 3343:{package}/u0a142 (adj 900): stop {package}

ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 3343

Comment: Are you want to clear `SharedPreferences` ?

Comment: I want to clear the user data,the code above is doing the job of clearing but I want to restart the app myself if the res comes back as true.

Comment: Don't save data to the disk in the first place, if you do not want that data to survive process termination.

Comment: I want to save the data because I want to be able to switch from one config to another, I want to be able to check my prod and pre-prod config at runtime when I'm in debug mode. I've some stuff save in SQLite which will be a problem if I don't clear the data

Answer (score 0):

`clearApplicationUserData()` is designed to work like that, once you call it, the app process will be killed without any warning.
According to what you described, you only need to delete the database manually and recreate a new one instead of resetting the whole app data which doesn't answer your request efficiently.

Comment: That method returns back a boolean which mean the documentation is wrong.